# COMSOL - 2D box - get for every x an average value over y (line average apply for more lines)

Tags: comsol

I would like to ask you for your help.

I have 2D box. I know how to do an 2D cut line and compute an average value of someting over this line. (in Results -> Data Sets -> Cut Line 2D and then Results->Derived Values->Line Average and choose Cut Line 2D 1).

But I would need to know this average value for many of such parallel Cut Lines. I need to compute a curve of average value of something in y for every x. Have you any idea how to get it? I have tried to produce in Cut Line 2D the Additional parallel lines and then do average on it but the result was one number. I wanted a number for every cut line.

How can I do it? I would like to get an average value of pressure (in y) as a function of coordinate x.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp.SE! Your question seems to be about the use of the COMSOL GUI - not really what this site is good for. You should ask such product specific questions on the [support forum](http://www.comsol.com/support/).

Comment: @ChristianClason This site is good for such a question. What you probably meant was that this question is not good for the site? Perhaps you can suggest a better fitting StackExchange site for this question?

Comment: I had to do something similar, and the only way I found was to use the `mphinterp` function provided by Comsol's Matlab API, sample along enough points in y, and add the values up (do this for each x of interest). In general, Matlab API allows you to do a lot more than the Comsol GUI, and getting started with it is a good investment. Especially if you work with complex or large models.